# One query and articles in multiple boxes

Tags: php, mysql

I would like to list multible articles on index.php with one query and foreach function.

But I don't know if it's possible or not, can you guys show me an example how to do it please?

I can do it but showing same posts in all boxes, I would like to show different posts in each box.

Sorry for my bad English :(

Example:

```html
   <?php
include("header.php");
  
  /* Slider  */
  $query = $db->read_query("SELECT id, title, spot, image, date, cuff, type
                                    FROM news
         WHERE active = 'Y'
         AND cuff_view = 'Y'
         ORDER BY date DESC
         LIMIT 10") or die($db->sql_error());
                   $HeadNews = array();
                   while($row = $db->sql_fetcharray($query)){
    $HeadNews[] = $row;
                    }
                    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Posts</title>
</head>
<body>
**// first article box**
  <h1>fruits</h1>
  <ul>
<?php
foreach($HeadNews as $k=>$news){
 $news_url_seo = $news[id]."-".seo($news[title]).".html";
?>
      <li><?php echo stripslashes($news[image]);?>" width="350" /></li>
      <li><p><?=stripslashes($news[spot])?>.</p>
   <a href="<?=$news_url_seo;?>">Details</a></li>
 <?php } ?>
  </ul>
**// second article box**
<h1>fruits 2</h1>
<ul>
   <?php
foreach($HeadNews as $k=>$news){
 $news_url_seo = $news[id]."-".seo($news[title]).".html";
?>
      <li><?php echo stripslashes($news[image]);?>" width="350" /></li>
      <li><p><?=stripslashes($news[spot])?>.</p>
   <a href="<?=$news_url_seo;?>">Details</a></li>
 <?php } ?>
  </ul>
**// Third article box**
<h1>fruits 3</h1>
<ul>
    <?php
foreach($HeadNews as $k=>$news){
 $news_url_seo = $news[id]."-".seo($news[title]).".html";
?>
      <li><?php echo stripslashes($news[image]);?>" width="350" /></li>
      <li><p><?=stripslashes($news[spot])?>.</p>
   <a href="<?=$news_url_seo;?>">Details</a></li>
 <?php } ?>
  </ul>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post a sample of the desired output.

Comment: Show what you have tried? SO is not a code writing service. Please lookup "how to ask a question" on Stackoverflow for helpful information about how to ask a question and what types of questions are allowed.

Answer (score 1):

I haven't tested my answer, but this should give you a basic idea.
I hope you understand how to use a foreach loop by looking at this code.

```
   <?php
include("header.php");

        /* Slider  */
        $query = $db->read_query("SELECT id, title, spot, image, date, cuff, type
                                    FROM news
                                    WHERE active = 'Y'
                                    AND cuff_view = 'Y'
                                    ORDER BY date DESC
                                    LIMIT 10") or die($db->sql_error());
                   $HeadNews = array();
                   while($row = $db->sql_fetcharray($query)){
                        //Populate the array
                        $HeadNews[$row[id]] = $row;
                    }
                    ?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <title>Posts</title>
</head>
<body>
**// Create all article boxes**
<?php
foreach($HeadNews as $k=>$news){
 //For each item in the array, create an article box
 $news_url_seo = $news[id]."-".seo($news[title]).".html";
?>
  <h1>fruits <?php echo $k ?></h1>
  <ul>

      <li><?php echo stripslashes($news[image]);?>" width="350" /></li>
      <li><p><?=stripslashes($news[spot])?>.</p>
            <a href="<?=$news_url_seo;?>">Details</a></li>

  </ul>
 <?php } ?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for the answer jesse, I stil get same posts when I use your method. can u give me an example of array please

Comment: I think the problems lies in populating the array from the database. You can best use print_r to view the contents of $HeadNews after the while loop and check what's wrong.

Comment: Should I use news ID's in array for each box ? $a = array_fill(5, 6, 'banana');
$b = array_fill(-2, 4, 'pear');
print_r($a);
print_r($b);